# Get top 10 users data based on the number of sales

Tags: mysql

I have table 'sales' and data like this scheme:

```
User    | Amount| Month
user a      100     1
user b      240     1
user c      120     1
user a      200     2
user b      130     2
user c      240     2
```

How to get TOP 5 user based on Total Sales every month, I've tried using query like this, but there's always showed an error

```
SELECT TOP10 USER, 
   SUM(amount) amount
    FROM   sales LIMIT 10
WHERE  MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 12
GROUP BY sales
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

And the result should be:

```
User a | 300
User b | 370
User c | 360
```

So the order must be: B, C, A

Comment: limit should be after order by,there is no top10 field and if you want to TOP 5 user based on Total Sales then grouping on user might be more effective than grouping by a table. Overall you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: do you need month wise top 5 users ?

Comment: The question is unclear (because the question as written conflicts with your attempted query)- it would help if you added desired result based on the sample data as text to the question.

Comment: @fa06 Yes , and it based top sales sum

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, I've adding more description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `GROUP BY` on `User`, and use `SUM(amount)` to get the `total_sales` per user. Now, simply sort the result-set by `total_sales` in Descending order, to get the highest sales first.

We can use `LIMIT 10`, in case you want to get only Top 10.

```
SELECT User, 
       SUM(amount) AS total_sales 
FROM sales 
WHERE MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 12
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: But how if I want to get a data from two tables ?

Comment: @RiandyEka you can join between the tables using their appropriate Join relationships. However, if it is not clear, you may post another question. You will definitely get the answers there

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
SELECT USER, SUM(amount) amount
FROM   sales 
WHERE  MONTH BETWEEN 1 AND 12
GROUP BY USER
ORDER BY amount DESC
```